# Rename variables in subclass

Tags: java

I have a simple tuple class.

```
public class Tuple<X, Y> { 
    public X first; 
    public Y second; 
    public Tuple(X x, Y y) { 
        this.first = x; 
        this.second = y; 
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + first + "," + second + ")";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (other == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(other instanceof Tuple)){
            return false;
        }
        Tuple<X,Y> other_ = (Tuple<X,Y>) other;
        return other_.first == this.first && other_.second == this.second;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((first == null) ? 0 : first.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((second == null) ? 0 : second.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
}
```

I use it in several different contexts. I have tuples of articles and their ID, their ID and their vector weight, etc. After a while, it gets messy only seeing `first` and `second` as the variable names, when they could mean stuff like `name` and `id`. Is there any way i can subclass this class multiple times to rename `first` and `second` to meaningful names, without needing to override `toString()`, `equals()`, and `hashCode()`?

Comment: You want to create a subclass that uses variable names that are not in the super class but you still wan tot use ``equals()`` and ``hashCode()`` from the super class?

Comment: pretty much, i just want to see meaningful names instead of first and second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass `Tuple` and add extra getters with meaningful names. Also the constructor parameters are named. You can also enforce `id` to be not nullable, by declaring it as `int` in the constructor.

```
public class NameIdTuple extends Tuple<String, Integer> {

    public NameIdTuple(String name, int id) {
        super(name, id);
    }

    public String name() {
        return first;
    }

    public int id() {
        return second;
    }

}
```

Methods `getFirst()` and `getSecond()` still can be called (so you have full backwards compatibility).

I don't know which IDE you are using, but IntelliJ's auto-completion shows methods declared in the class in bold, others such as `getClass()`, `equals()`, `getFirst()` won't be in bold so it's unlikely that they will be used in the new code.

Comment: Nice, this is what i wanted. Thanks.